# After installing Office 2013 my VB6 app crashes opening an Access table

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2013

Thanks for reading. A customer has installed Office 2013 and as a consequence my VB6 app crashes when trying to read from my apps database. The database was previously a 2010 Access DB. The following line is an example of where it crashes.

```
lRS.Open "select BirthDate,CityTown,StateProvince,Country,Weight,Height,Apgarscore,PerinatalProblems,Prefix+' '+Firstname+' '+Middlename+' '+Lastname+' '+Suffix as IndividualName,Hospital,WeightUnit,HeightUnit from tblBirthInformation a left join tblIndividual b on a.DeliveredBy=b.IndividualID and a.PatientID=b.PatientID where a.PatientID=" & gPMRID, gconn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

In References I am using  msado60_Backcompat_i386.tlb  which I read some time back is what I should be using for current versions of Access. To date it has worked fine.

I can't understand why installing Access 2013 would crash the app.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some information on what "my app crashes" might mean? Do you get an exception? Is there an error message? Can you provide *any details* about the actual problem other than "my app crashes"?

Comment: There really isn't any such thing as an "Access DB" though there are two types of file-based DBMSs that Access can use and dump private structures into (UserForms, etc.).  These are Jet MDBs and ACE ACCDBs.  Are you using MDBs or ACCDBs?  Jet 4.0 is quite stable while ACE comes out in a new flavor with every new Access version.

Comment: The "backcompat" type library has nothing directly to do with Access, let alone "current versions" of Access.  It's about Win7 SP1 breaking ADO for new development on that OS - for anything from Jet to SQL Server to Chalk & Cheese DB.  Programs compiled on Win7 RTM, Vista, XP, etc. should still run on Win7 SP1 with no problem since the typelib isn't used at runtime.